# Equivalence of 2 differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone spot why this equivalence is true?

$f=f(x)$

$$f'''-(k+6f)f'=0$$ and $$c_1+c_2f+{k\over 2}f^2+f^3-{1\over 2} (f')^2=0$$
where $c_1,c_2$ can be any pair of constants.

I think the ${1\over 2}(f')^2$ is very suggestive, but I just can't see it.

EDIT: Ah, I have just spotted the link! Thanks for reading anyway!

Comment: We don't use [SOLVED] in the title. Instead we **accept answers** to indicate that the problem has been solved. You can also post an answer of your own and accept if you wish.

Comment: Sorry, @AsafKaragila, I have deleted the [SOLVED] now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first differential equation can be integrated directly to give:
$$f'' - kf - 3f^2 + a = 0.$$
Multiply this equation by $f'$
$$f'f'' - kff' - 3f^2f' + af' = 0.$$
Now integrate again.
$$\frac{1}{2}(f')^2 - \frac{k}{2}(f)^{2} - f^{3} + af +b =0.$$
This is the second differential equation you've provided.